# Why semicolon is red in my c# dotnet 7 script in vscode?

Tags: c#, .net-core

[Screenshot of error message in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kbzn.png)

```cs
using System;
namespace CodeWarTests
{
    class Program 
    {         
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            private int test = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

I'm expecting not red semicolon.

Comment: In your screenshot, there's a colon (`:`) after the zero, not a semicolon.

Comment: @AKX That's just the second error in the snippet. The screenshot shows an error on the `;` in the `Console.WriteLine()` line, which is caused by the wrong assumption that local variables also need to be declared private.

Answer (score 3):

The `private` qualifier is for members of the class, not for local variables. It shows that it therefore expected a `}` after the `;` in your line 10.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1513

Therefore the following version should not show any error:

```cs
using System;
namespace CodeWarTests
{
    class Program 
    {         
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            int test = 0;
        }
    }

}
```